# Validation with parsley after re-enabling fields

Tags: html, forms, validation, parsley.js

I am working on a form that has two pages, technically 1 page, just hiding the second until first is finished. My first task was to be able to "validate" the first page with parsley.js, without including the elements from the second page. I did this by
disabling (via attr) the elements on the second page. Therefore only leaving the items on the first to be validated when the "Next" button is clicked. 
This works great!, unfortunately on the second page, after I removeAttr('disabled') from the elements, parsley ignores them and still only validates the first page, thus returning "true" and submitting the page  without checking any elements from the second.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 6):

Ok so I figured this out just in case someone runs into this in the future.

After I loaded the second page, I destroyed the parsley and then re-added after the elements were re-enabled.

```
$('.new-account #page1 #next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if ($('#new-account-form').parsley('isValid') == true) {
        $('#new-account-form .hide input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.new-account #page1').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.new-account #page2').fadeIn(500);
        });
        // destroy
        $('#new-account-form').parsley('destroy');
        // Re-assign parsley to the form to include the second page now
        $('#new-account-form').parsley();

    } else {
        $('#new-account-form').parsley('validate');
    }
});
```

Comment: Had to use parsley 1.x rather than 2.x and you just saved my life.